Font Awesome Icon not displaying in fixed bottom section on mobile device 320px Width
I'm experiencing an issue with a Font Awesome icon not displaying properly on a mobile device with a screen width of 320px. I'm using Bootstrap for the layout and Font Awesome for the icons. The problem specifically occurs with the Account icon in my fixed bottom navigation bar.
When accessing the website on a mobile device with a 320px screen width, only half of the Account icon is displayed. This issue is happens to this specific icon, as the other icons are displaying without any problems. Attempted to use different Font Awesome icon classes for the Account icon, but the issue is not resolved.
How can I solve this problem?


.fixed-bottom-section {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1000;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); 
}
.fixed-bottom-section .my_icons {
    margin-left: -35px;
}
.fixed-bottom-section .my_icons a:hover {
    color: #007bff;
}
.my_icons a {
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.my_icons a:hover {
    color: #007bff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.my_icons i {
    font-size: 20px; 
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px; 
}
.my_icons p {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.7.1/css/all.min.css">
        <section class="fixed-bottom-section">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                            <div class="col text-center">
                                <div class="my_icons d-flex justify-content-between">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link text-center">
                                        <i class="fa-solid fa-house-chimney"></i>
                                        <p>Home</p>
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="{% url 'Transaction' %}" class="nav-link text-center">
                                        <i class="fa-solid fa-rotate-right"></i>
                                        <p>Transaction</p>
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="{% url 'Wallet_Summary' %}" class="nav-link text-center">
                                        <i class="fa-solid fa-money-bill"></i>
                                        <p>History</p>
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link text-center">
                                        <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
                                        <p>Fund</p>
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="{% url 'Account' %}" class="nav-link text-center">
                                        <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
                                        <p>Account</p>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>




The issue of the Font Awesome "Account" icon being cut off on a mobile device with a screen width of 320px is likely caused by insufficient spacing or alignment issues within the .my_icons container in your navigation bar.

couple solutions:
1- Use flex-wrap to avoid clipping
Enable wrapping for the .my_icons container so icons wrap to the next line when the screen width is too small:
.fixed-bottom-section .my_icons {
    margin-left: 0; 
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
}

2- Adjust justify-content for center alignment
.fixed-bottom-section .my_icons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around; 
    margin-left: 0; 
}

